# VS 2012 Coded UI Testing and WPF User Control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have an application that uses a UserControl inside of a Window, Coded UI Testing recognizes everything in the Window (buttons, etc.) but inside the UserControl I just get a blue box around the area and cannot select anything inside for recording.

I've been all over google for this issue and I think it has to do with the AutomationPeers (?). Any suggestions would be useful in how to get these elements visible to Coded UI

Answer (score 0):

If the custom control doesn't provide a customized/override version of the [OnCreateAutomationPeer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165614(v=vs.110).aspx), you can't. You need to ask developers to implement automation support for their control.

Comment: You're right, I found this solution to help me out: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/genericautomationpeer--helping-the-coded-ui-framework-find-your-custom-controls

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

My issue was that Coded UI couldn't see past my TabControl (displays different user controls). I followed this solution to create a CustomTabControl and override the OnCreationAutomationPeer() method so that the lower elements could be displayed.

[ [click here](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/genericautomationpeer--helping-the-coded-ui-framework-find-your-custom-controls) ]